# Android app database to Azure

Tags: android, azure

I have android application developed, its uses sqlite database when application launches first time and inserted with static data (1 table with 2K records). I want to secure the data which I am inserting to database.
If any one get my apk and can analyse the class files and extract my 2K records. Because, insert query values are hard coded in class files.

I have 2 challenges

1. I have to secure this data from hackers (the insert statement should not be displayed in class files).
2. In future if any changes to this static data, I have to release new build to store.

To resolve above options, I have option to go ahead with Azure usage. Here are my questions:

1. How can I keep my static data base in azure and accessed (What is the best way)?
2. How to secure the Azure DB, It can be access only via mobile app with only read permission. I do not have any users or roles.
3. I do not have any service code, Is any built in features provided by Azure (like DB table with OData services)?

Comment: As written, this is unfortunately too broad. Azure has many data options (various SQL database services, Cosmos DB, Azure Storage, etc). Each has its own security model. Then there's the question of direct-connect to database (which means you're embedding credentials) vs API tier. For question #1, there is no "best" way, since we have no details of your app. For #2, as I said, each db (or Storage account) has its own specific credentials model. For #3, you can look at the access offerings of each storage type.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon for your response. As you suggested, which data base services is suits for my requirement? Read-Only feature form mobile side, It can access via only mobile applications unique id?

Answer (score 1):

As David Makogon commented that your question is too broad, but I would provide you with my ideas based on your requirement. You could follow the details below:

> 1.How can I keep my static data base in azure and accessed (What is the best way)?

We could only provide some suggestions / tutorials for your reference based on our understanding of your question. You need to find proper azure service(s) to meet your actual scenario by yourself.

> 2.How to secure the Azure DB, It can be access only via mobile app with only read permission. I do not have any users or roles.

You could leverage [Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) for exposing table endpoints to your authenticated users/clients with the limited permissions. Details you could follow the tutorials below:

[Create an Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started)

[Add authentication to your Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users)

[How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library).

**Note:** If your app does not have any users or roles, someone could also use some tools to capture the network traces between your mobile client and your backend, but this approach is more secure than just hard coded in the class files.

> 3.I do not have any service code, Is any built in features provided by Azure (like DB table with OData services)?

You could just leverage Azure Mobile Apps which support OData query (e.g.  Filters, Selects, Skip/Take (paging) and IncludeTotalCount). For a simple approach, you could follow Quick start on Azure Portal to initialize your Node.js backend for your Azure Mobile App, then go to "MOBILE > Easy tables" to create your new tables and set the proper permissons exposed to the clients. For advanced operations, you could follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/) for detailed instructions.